# For an integral domain $R$ and its quotient field $F=Frac(R)$, is it correct to say $R\subset F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

For an integral domain $R$ and its quotient field $F=Frac(R)$, is it correct to say $R\subset F$? Certainly have an embedding $\pi: R\to F, a\mapsto a\cdot(1)^{-1}$

Answer (score 4):

Technically, the underlying set of $R$ is not the underlying set of $F$.

However, the embedding you describe does identify $R$ as a subset of $F$; note that $R$ is isomorphic as a ring to $\operatorname{Im} \pi$, which is a subset of $F$.

From the point of view of ring theory, everyone is going to know what you mean if you write $R\subset F$.  One school of thought is that the *correct* definition of a subring of a ring $F$ is a ring $R$, together with an embedding $R\hookrightarrow F$, rather than an actual, set-theoretic, subset.

Comment: Yes, a subring of a ring $S$ is just an injective ring homomorphism $R \to S$. More generally, a subobject of an object $X$ of a category is just a monomorphism $U \to X$. There is no need to involve any forgetful functors to $\mathsf{Set}$, or to use any ZFC-interpretation of subsets. This is rather outdated and useless.